# Gtk+ 3 make GtkTreeView render columns horizontally

Tags: python, gtk, gtk3

I'm using Gtk+ 3 in a Python program I'm working on and I need the "columns" in a GtkTreeView to be rendered in horizontally instead of the vertical way they are now.

As you can see from [this GIF](http://gfycat.com/SanePastCopperhead), because the attachment names stack up, it expands the TreeView upwards, *not* what I want.

I'm using Glade to design the GUI and I can't find any options for this, nor can I find any mention of it in the [Gtk+ 3 Docs](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTreeView.html).

Is this possible, or am I going to have to figure out how to hack a solution with multiple columns?

I want it to end up looking something like this:

[image]

Comment: What specific version of GTK+ is your minimum requirement?

Comment: Also just to be sure, you're saying you want a list that works like [this one](https://i-msdn.sec.s-msft.com/dynimg/IC725349.png)?

Comment: @andlabs Minimum is Gtk 3.0. As for the way I want it to look, I would like it to be like this: http://i.imgur.com/1BrcaFY.png. Should've added an example in the question.

Comment: If you are referring to the "Attachments" area in the picture, it can be done with Gtk.Labels in a Gtk.FlowBox unless you need special features of a TreeView.

Comment: @elya5 If I can make the labels right-clickable, then I'm fine with that. Can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a Gtk.FlowBox with Gtk.Labels, you can do it like this. However, there is probably a better way than packing every Gtk.Label in a Gtk.EventBox.

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk
import string


class Window(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.connect('delete-event', Gtk.main_quit)
        self.set_size_request(200, 150)
        flowbox = Gtk.FlowBox()
        self.add(flowbox)

        for x in string.ascii_lowercase:
            eventbox = Gtk.EventBox()
            eventbox.add(Gtk.Label(label=x))
            flowbox.add(eventbox)
            eventbox.connect('button-press-event', self.on_button_press)

    def on_button_press(self, widget, event):
        if event.button == 3:
            print('Right click on: ' + widget.get_child().get_text())


win = Window()
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Comment: @RPiAwesomeness be aware that GtkFlowBox was introduced in GTK+ 3.12, so if you do go with that your minimum GTK+ version becomes 3.12. (I was thinking of GtkFlowBox too, but the version requirement was why I was asking.)

Comment: @andlabs That's fine. I was able to set it up just fine using the Glade GUI I already had going.